# React Same component mounted and unmounted multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

When i switch between two tabs in my react app useEffect calls api everytime.

Is it fine to call api on every time on the page mount or only in the first time page mount.

If only in first time page mount if we call api,then how to handle data freshness in that page in second mount?

Answer (score 1):

It is up to your needs when to call api call and how important to keep the freshness of data. you can either call api call on switch tab or you go one level up and set this to their parents where switch tabs is the children.
you can use many tools like react query, redux , custom caching and etc to handle your needs.